# Prevent zoom on Blackberry Storm

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-storm

For web pages that are being viewed in the iPhone, you can add the following meta tag to disable to zoom feature:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=320; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=0;"/>
```

Is there something to do the same for the Blackberry Storm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BlackBerry® Device Software 4.6 and later supports the meta tag you specified.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=320; initial-scale=1.0;
 maximum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=0;"/>
```

It also supports the HandheldFriendly tag:

```
<meta name="HandheldFriendly" content="true" />
```

I tested both tags on my 9700 and both independently disabled the zoom cursor.

[How To Article From Blackberry.com](http://www.blackberry.com/knowledgecenterpublic/livelink.exe/fetch/2000/348583/800878/800733/How_To_-_Control_the_BlackBerry_Browser_zoom_level.html?nodeid=1444381&vernum=0)

Comment: this does work on Blackberry however, nothing else can be zoomed on the page with that header. you may wish to specify this only where required.